# how to duplicate rows by condition and replace content in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I would like to dublicate rows of my data frame by testing a condition and then changing the contensts of variables.

My original data frame is this :

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("x", "y", "w"), decision = c("partial", "refusal", "total"),
             code = c("AAA20", "AAA61", "AAA77"), `2nd_decision` = c("total", "partial", NA),
             `2nd_code` = c("BBB50", "BBB89", NA), varx = c("a", "v", "p"))



id   decision    code   2nd_decision  2nd_code  varx
 x    partial   AAA20    total          BBB50    a
 y    refusal   AAA61    partial        BBB89    v
 w    total     AAA77                            p
```

I would like to test each time that 2nd_decision is "partial" or "total", and if so, duplicate the row and replace the contents of the variables "decision" and "code" with "2nd_decision" and "2nd_code" ; also, I do not want to present any more the content of "2nd_decision" and "2nd_code" and keep the rest of my data frame as it was, like this:

```
id   decision    code   2nd_decision  2nd_code  varx 
 x    partial   AAA20    total          BBB50    a
 y    refusal   AAA61    partial        BBB89    v
 w    total     AAA77                            p
 x    total     BBB50                            a
 y    partial   BBB89                            v
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide your data in code format so it can be easily read in R. Eg.

    data.frame(".......")

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("x", "y", "w"), decision = c("partial", "refusal", "total"),
                 code = c("AAA20", "AAA61", "AAA77"), `2nd_decision` = c("total", "partial", NA),
                 `2nd_code` = c("BBB50", "BBB89", NA), varx = c("a", "v", "p"))

add_rows <- unique(df[, c("id", "X2nd_decision", "X2nd_code", "varx")])
colnames(add_rows) <- c("id", "decision", "code", "varx")
add_rows <- add_rows[!is.na(add_rows$decision), ]

library(plyr)
df_final <- rbind.fill(df, add_rows)
df_final
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mutate` in combination with an `ifelse` statement.

Let's recreate your data first.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("x", "y", "w", "x", "y"),
                 decision = c("partial", "refusal", "total", "total", "partial"),
                 code = c("AAA20", "AAA61", "AAA77", "BBB50", "BBB89"),
                 decision2 = c("total", "partial", NA, NA, NA),
                 varx = c("a", "v", "p", "a", "v"))
```

And here the code to test second decision and remove unwanted variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfnew <- df %>% 
  mutate(code = ifelse(decision2 == "total", "BBB50",
                ifelse(decision2 == "partial", "BBB89", NA))) %>% 
  select(-decision2)
```

Comment: You can also use the `case_when()`  function from `dplyr` if you want to avoid nested `ifelse()`.  `df %>% mutate(code = case_when(decision2 == "total" ~ "BBB50",
                              decision2 == "partial" ~ "BBB89",
                              TRUE ~ as.character(decision2)))`